# Process migration isen't working in the current version? (11.11.8.0)

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I try to migrate a process from one azure devops org to another with the Azure DevOps Migration Tool.
In the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64344322/is-there-sample-test-plan-migration-config-for-version-11-5/64385839#64385839) it is said if you run this command `migration.exe init --options Full` you get the complete configuration options that are available. But in the created configuraition file I can't find a processor for the process migration.
In your [GitHub](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/) documentation there are hints that it should be possible, so I am a little confused.

Are they diffrent versions on [GitHub](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/) and [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/vsts-sync-migrator/#releasenotes)?

If I compare the version number and the release date (on the sites) then it seems they have the same version.

In the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/) I found the *ProcessDefinitionProcessor* and tryed to find the correct configuration.
At the end i got this error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Type specified in JSON 'MigrationTools.Processors.ProcessDefinitionProcessor, MigrationTools.Clients.AzureDevops.Rest, Version=11.11.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not compatible with 'MigrationTools._EngineV1.Configuration.IProcessorConfig, MigrationTools, Version=11.11.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Path 'Processors[1].$type', line 150, position 43.
```

With this configuration:

```
  "Processors": [   
{
  "$type": "ProcessDefinitionProcessor",
  "Enabled": true,
  "Processes": {
                "Scrum":["IWB_Scrum_VD"]
                }
}
  ],
  "Version": "11.11",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure DevOps Migration tools does not migrate the Process, just the Work Items.

You can use the Microsoft project `process-migrator` to migrate the process.